# HTTP redirects 301 and 302 have different content encoding

Tags: http, redirect

Could somebody explain me, how can it be, that on the same website one url, which is redirected with code `301` has as content type `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`, and another url from the same website, which is redirected with code `302` has as content type `text/html; charset=UTF-8`?

Comment: Does it really matter? Individual responses are allowed to use different data types and encodings. HTTP is stateless, you have to process each response individually and completely. There is no requirement or guarantee that an entire website uses a single consistent encoding. It is whatever the site owner uploaded and configured. Maybe one file was uploaded as UTF-8 and the other wasn't so the server guessed or used a default

Comment: hm, this is a right question. about whether it is really matter. It was an output of a third party crawler programm, which is normally absolutely correct, but.... i ask developer